# How do I insert a string after a certain string but before the next occurrence of a specific character?

Tags: regex, ruby

Given a name of an operation (B_OPERATIONS for instance), insert a string before the next occurrence of "]" following B_OPERATIONS **using regex**. It should be dynamic, for instance the name of the operation given can change. I am using Ruby.

What I currently have:

```
A_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_name
                          release_name
                         ].freeze

B_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_team
                          delete_team
                         ].freeze
                    
C_OPERATIONS = %w[
                         email_user
                         ].freeze
```

What I want:

```
A_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_name
                          release_name
                         ].freeze

B_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_team
                          delete_team
                          <I WANT TO PUT STRING HERE>
                         ].freeze
                    
C_OPERATIONS = %w[
                         email_user
                         ].freeze
```

The string in IRB looks like this:

```
str = "A_OPERATIONS = %w[\n                          update_name\n                          release_name\n                         ].freeze\n\nB_OPERATIONS = %w[\n                          update_team\n                          delete_team\n                         ].freeze\n                    \nC_OPERATIONS = %w[\n                         email_user\n                         ].freeze"
```

I have been trying using capture groups but I haven't made much progress, My thought process is define a pattern to filter down the string to what is included in the brackets [] after the given name of the operation, then find the last \n and append the string there but I haven't gotten there yet.

```
str.gsub(/(B_OPERATIONS = \%w\[)(.*)(?=\.freeze)/, <the string included inbetween the brackets following the name of the operation + the string I want to include>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the closing `]` is always on a separate line than the `[`, you can match the number of indenting spaces before the closing `]` and use those in the replacement using the full match `\\0`

```
B_OPERATIONS = %w\[[^\]\[]*\R\K[^\S\r\n]*(?=[^\]\[]*\])
```

- `B_OPERATIONS = %w\[` Match `B_OPERATIONS = %w[`
- `[^\]\[]*` Match 0+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `\R\K` Match a newline and forget what is matched so far
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional spaces without a newline
- `(?=[^\]\[]*\])` Positive lookahead, assert a `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/hBn2GhNUB7snYL) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/luJBfl)

The line in Ruby

```
str.gsub(/B_OPERATIONS = %w\[[^\]\[]*\R\K[^\S\r\n]*(?=[^\]\[]*\])/, "\\0<I WANT TO PUT STRING HERE>\n\\0")
```

Output

```
A_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_name
                          release_name
                         ].freeze

B_OPERATIONS = %w[
                          update_team
                          delete_team
                         <I WANT TO PUT STRING HERE>
                         ].freeze
                    
C_OPERATIONS = %w[
                         email_user
                         ].freeze
```

Without matching the spaces, you could also get the position before the closing `]` and add the replacement there.

```
B_OPERATIONS = %w\[[^]\[]*\K(?=[^\]\[]*\])
```

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/YiCn4NidwbgTiC) | [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/vRDINp)